# SSRS blank pages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an issue where if my SSRS chart does not fit on the entire report, it causes a blank page and goes to the next. Is there a way to configure the report so that if the chart cannot fit then just go to the next page?

Things I have already tried:
Set ConsumeWhiteSpace to true
Made sure my report body is smaller than the Page width minus the margins
Made the charts smaller

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do think so.  This is off the top of my head but I hope it leads you down the right path.  If you put the chart in a rectangle - I think you need to get this property - you can then set the "Keep Together" properties for the chart and it will force it onto its own page as necessary.

If I get a minute I will test with some of my own reports here.

Comment: Yes so the charts are in a rectangle and ive set the property to both true and false with no luck.

Comment: Strange. If I understand you right, you want the chart on the same page as a table unless the table grows, then move the chart to its own page.  Is that right?  Not sure if there is a way but can you share your .rdl file?

Comment: Like say I have table then a chart then table then a chart, if that last chart cant fit on the page then just move it to the next page dont skip a page